# слайдер Swiper при клике на кнопки next / prew выделяеться текст заголовка

Tags: javascript, css3, swiper, swiper.js

слайдер Swiper  при клике на кнопки next / prew  выделяться текст заголовка. Не могу понять из-за чего происходит выделение текста.

Тут можно глянуть баг долистав до товаров.
https://dmitry-rogg.vn.ua/alpinair/

Видео с демо бага
https://www.loom.com/share/94126f309e89454ba8374a2d909081ab?sid=0381aabc-7a80-48b2-bfef-41aa78831be0

Comment: Попробуйте добавить кнопкам переключения CSS свойство `user-select: none;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: Второй вариант сделать кнопки не div, а как полагается button

Comment: Спасибо первый вариант работает

Comment: Второй предпочтительнее, т.к. это нативный элемент кнопки!